# How to call Mailable function from Controller?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am new to laravel and worked through the [laravel mailable doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail) which ended me with a `mailable` that looks like this:

**`ContactMail.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use http\Env\Request;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;


class ContactMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

  public function __construct()
  {
    //
  }

  public function build()
  {

    return $this->markdown('emails.contact');
  }

  public function store(Request $request)
  {

    $contactVar = 'hello world!';

    Mail::to($request->user())->send(new contact($contactVar));

  }
}
```

I want the **`store`** function of this `mailable` to be called from my **`ContactController.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;


class ContactController extends Controller
{
  public function submit(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required | email',
      'message' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    // store(...)
    
    return response()->json(null, 200);
  }
}
```

How would I call the function and is this good practice? Sorry if it's obvious, I'm trying to get the hang of `Laravel/PHP`.

This is the corresponding `email template file` (**`contact.blade.php`**):

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction

The body of your message.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653747/how-to-send-data-from-laravel-controller-to-mailable-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send Data from Laravel Controller to Mailable Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653747/how-to-send-data-from-laravel-controller-to-mailable-class)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use view, your mailable should return view in the `store` method. You can read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#via-public-properties).

So your mailable should look more like this:

```php
class ContactMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
  // the rest of the code

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    return $this->view('contact');
  }
}
```

And then you can send mail to user in your `Controller` like this:

```php
Mail::to($request->user())->send(new ContactMail());
```

What you can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#sending-mail).

---

Also, if you want to use variables in your view, you can use `with` method, and there you can pass associative array with named variables:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
  return $this->view('contact')
              ->with(['contactVariable' => 'hello world!']);
}
```

And to use this variable you just type `$contactVariable` in your view template.

Comment: Hey, this seems to work but now I am getting a `local.ERROR: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`. Any idea how to solve this? I don't have `xamp/wamp` installed but am just using `artisan server`.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: I know, but is this solution not for `xamp/wamp` users? I am just using `artisan server`. Or is `xamp` integrated by default?

Comment: So the `cURL` error is gone but the `ContactMail` function inside `ContactController.php` does not seem to call `store` function.

Comment: **Does not seem to call store function**, what does it mean? What is your current result, what you want to do, what you have tried? Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is to create a job and dispatch the mail load to this job. The job structure is shown below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

   
    protected $email;
    public function __construct($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::to($this->email)->send(new ContactMail());
    }
}
```

And dispatch the job from your controllers submit method like this.

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
  public function submit(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required | email',
      'message' => 'required'
    ]);
    SendMail::dispatch($request->email)->onQueue('send_mail');
    // store(...)
    return response()->json(null, 200);
  }

}
```

Remove the store method from the ContactMail.php file